# PHP regex, space or no character

Tags: php, regex, space

Ok Im trying to figure out this regex where I have a word, and on either end of the word it can be a space or no character. Heres an example:

```
preg_match_all("/( ?)(" . $piece . ")( ?)/is", $fk, $sub);
```

Where `( ?)` is I want that to be "A single character that can only be a space or no character at all". Im trying to basically make a function that checks whether something is a word or not based on its surrounding characters. And `$piece` is the word, so It has to be by itself, not part of another longer word if you know what I mean. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for the word boundary assertion `\b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test for a space or no character, use the following syntax:

`preg_match_all("/(^| )(" . $piece . ")( |$)/is", $fk, $sub);`

The `(^| )` means: Match either beginning of string (so called "no character") or space. The `( |$)` means: Match space or end of string (again, a "no character"). The beginning and end of a string are the only places where there is no character.

Comment: Wouldn't using \b would be more appropriate?

Comment: \b matches non-word characters. He specifically asked for "no char" or space. \b matches e.g. ( which is neither.